# Triangle inscribed in an ellipse

Tags: geometry, contest-math

What is the maximum area of a triangle that can be inscribed in an ellipse with semi-axes $a$ and $b$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is $3ab\sqrt{3}/4$.

When you stretch a circle so that it becomes an ellipse, areas are multiplied by a constant factor. Therefore it's enough to solve the problem for a circle of radius $1$ and multiply the result by $ab$.

In a circle with centre $O$ inscribe a triangle $ABC$ so that the area is maximal. Regarding   the base $AB$ as fixed, the area is maximized when the height is as large as possible, that is when $C$ is placed as far away from $AB$ as you can get it. This happens only when $ABC$ is isosceles with $AC = BC$. Since the same argument could have been made with respect to $A$ and $B$, this shows that the triangle must be equilateral. The area is then $3\sqrt{3}/4,$ which must be multiplied by $ab$ in the case of an ellipse.